# Automatic crop and straighten algorithm

Tags: image-processing, graphics, photo

I am building a using C#/.Net system to automatically crop and straighten multiple images in a scan of multiple photos, such as would result from scanning a page of a photo album. This can be done in Photoshop or using an ImageMagick script, but I'd like to put in some enhancements. I am using a flood-fill algorithm to create a uniform background and am wondering how to fit rectangles (possibly rotated by a few degrees) to the holes in the filled region corresponding to the individual photos. The holes sometimes have irregular parts in their boundaries where the photo is the same color as the background. Detecting the edges of the flood-filled region gives a set of pixels which approximately define the rectangles as shown below, but I would like to extract co-ordinates of the rectangle corners.

Can anyone suggest an algorithm for this purpose?

An example of a flood filled multiple photo image is below:

[image: Flood-filled multiple photo image]

Comment: Please take the **tour** (https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read the information guides in the **help center** (https://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular, "How to Ask A Good Question" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), "What Are Good Topics" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and "How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). How about an example photo and some code! What exactly have you tried?

Comment: I have tried using the horizontal and the vertical variance of pixels in grayscale image blocks for defining edges, and then a convolution operator to detect the 4 corner orientations but without success. Interior image features often give higher values than corners. The process is also quite slow - 5 seconds for an 8 Mpixel image, mostly for extracting pixels.

Comment: Post the original image. ImageMagick can extract the 4 pictures and rotate them to the closest 90 deg orientation. See connected components at https://imagemagick.org/script/connected-components.php and unrotate an image at https://imagemagick.org/script/convex-hull.php#unrotate

Comment: I need the co-ordinates of the individual rectangles of the component images for manual editing - can ImageMagick provide these?

Comment: Yes assuming you can isolate the background from the images in a reasonable way. The connected components processing will give you the bounding box coordinates of each isolated region. If you post a full resolution image, I will process your image in command line mode. Someone else on the ImageMagick forum will have to help you convert to Magick.NET.

Comment: Thanks for your offer. I'll try and use the script with the ImageMagick dll and report how I go. More basic methods of corner detection are proving difficult to make work without a lot of parameter adjustment.